# Use a variable created in a loop in other files - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, for-loop, methods, global-variables

I was wondering how I could use a variable that was created in a loop in other files. For example, I have this loop in my views :

```
<% for @p in @posts %>
    <%= @p.content %>
<% end %>
```

How could I use @p in a method that I created in my controller? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the p exist in your database? Could you not just reference the associated table and row id and send it to your controller? When a user clicks, send the associated ID off? Assuming that @p is a specific post of course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable that are created in loops, are technically created inside a block. The variables that are created in a block, are accessible to that block. Please read this https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-scope-in-ruby/

I am not sure why would anyone wants to use a variable that is created in a view in a controller, it's the reverse, **YOU SHOULD** use the variable that is created in the controller in views

Since you have tagged global variables in the question, if you want to use them anyways, `use $p instead of @p`